# greenDAO manyToMany reflexive relation

Tags: android, many-to-many, has-many-through, greendao

I am trying to figure out how to model this relation for Android in GreenDao.

We have a NavigationNode, which can have ManytoMany other NavigationNodes.

In Rails we modelled this with a 'has_many :through' with a NavigationPath join table:

```
class NavigationPoint < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :navigation_paths, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :paths, through: :navigation_paths, source: :navigation_point, dependent: :destroy
end

class NavigationPath < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :navigation_point_id, :connected_point_id
  belongs_to :navigation_point, foreign_key: :connected_point_id
end
```

And in iOS we just set it as a relation to self on NavigationNode:

```
Relationship    Destination         Inverse
-------------------------------------------
paths           NavigationNode      paths
```

But I can't seem to find the right configuration for greenDAO.

Any help / hint would be appreciated, thanks

### Update:

I implemented a temporary solution for now:

The DAO for NavigationPath (the join table):

```
Entity navigationPath = schema.addEntity("NavigationPath");
navigationPath.setSuperclass(SUPER_CLASS);
navigationPath.setIsJoinTable(true);
navigationPath.addIdProperty();
Property fromNavigationNodeProperty = navigationPath.addLongProperty("NavigationNodeID").getProperty();
Property toNavigationNodeProperty = navigationPath.addLongProperty("toNavigationNodeID").getProperty();
ToMany paths = navigationNode.addToMany(navigationPath, fromNavigationNodeProperty, "navigationPaths");

Index indexNavigationPath = new Index();
indexNavigationPath.addProperty(fromNavigationNodeProperty);
indexNavigationPath.addProperty(toNavigationNodeProperty);
indexNavigationPath.makeUnique();
navigationPath.addIndex(indexNavigationPath);
```

And here the custom relation method in NavigationPath:

```
public List<NavigationNode> getPaths(String where) {
    if (daoSession == null) {
        throw new DaoException("Entity is detached from DAO context");
    }
    NavigationPathDao pathDao = daoSession.getNavigationPathDao();
    QueryBuilder pathsQuery = pathDao.queryBuilder().where(NavigationPathDao.Properties.NavigationNodeID.eq(id));
    List<NavigationPath> navigationPaths = pathsQuery.list();

    List<NavigationNode> navigationNodesNew = new ArrayList<NavigationNode>();
    for (NavigationPath path : navigationPaths) {
        Long id = path.getToNavigationNodeID();
        NavigationNode node = myDao.load(id);
        if (node != null)
            navigationNodesNew.add(node);
    }
    return navigationNodesNew;
}
```

It's a pretty naive implementation, but for now it is working.

But again, tips are appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

From [greenDao website](http://greendao-orm.com/documentation/relations/):

> ### Many-to-Many Relations (n:m)
>
> In databases, n:m relations are modeled using a join table. The join
>   table holds entries having rows with foreign keys to each of the
>   relating tables. While greenDAO does not support n:m relations
>   directly as of now, you can model the join table as a separate entity.
>   In practice, you often have “relation entities” with additional
>   properties, so you might want to do so anyway. In future releases,
>   greenDAO might introduce direct support of n:m relations.

It seems that isn't possible at this moment without a relation entity, maybe you could try that.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I implemented a temporary solution for now